# How to convert PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this one:

```
array( array("key1" => "value1"), array("key2" => "value2"), ... )
```

I need to convert it to this format:

```
array( "value1", "value2", ... )
```

How can I do it using PHP?

Comment: I prefer using one or two core functions instead of looping or etc.

Comment: "instead of looping" anything wrong with it?

Comment: Anyway: `array_map` + `array_values` + `array_merge` + `call_user_func_array` is the comprehensive list of functions to do what you want

Comment: "That's more clear and simple" --- how do you know that, if you don't have it yet? :-D PS: there is a way, try to combine those 4 functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping would be acceptable in this case. If you do want an example without looping, you can use `array_map` but I don't think it would be more "clear and simple":

```
$array = array_map(function($value) {
    return reset($value);
}, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function SHOULD (untested) return a single array with no associative keys from your mufti-dimentional array.

```
function single_array ($array) {
    $array2 = array();
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                $array2[] = single_array($val);
            }else{
                $array2[] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    return $array2;
}

$array = single_array($array);
```

Comment: He has a multi-dimensional array, not just an array with string keys.

Comment: @Scopey You're right, I didn't see the multiple arrays.